# SSRS Remote server access

Tags: reporting-services, remote-server

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DSView'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
The feature: "The edition of Reporting Services that you are using requires that you use local SQL Server relational databases for report data sources and the report server database." is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsOperationNotSupported)

Hi, I have encountered the above mentioned error while doing an SSRS project. And from the research, it seems like it is SQL server related issue.

I am trying to access a remote SQL server....so I was wondering how can I get rid of that error?

Do I have to install SQL server Standard edition on my local machine or the server that I am trying to access should be installed with Sql Standard edition?

I have got Express editions installed on both my local machine and the server...
Thx

Answer (score 1):

From Books Online:

> Report data sources must be SQL Server relational databases that run
>   locally in SQL Server Express.

[Features Supported by Reporting Services in SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc281020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

With SQL Server Express you can only use a Data Source where the database engine is from the same instance  running SSRS.

If you need to connect to other instances your only options are to get a backup restored to your local instance or to install a SQL Server edition that allows remote Data Sources; most likely **Developer** for your own needs or **Standard** or above for any production instances.

It depends on what's allowed under your specific licencing agreement.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to get around this (that just worked for me) is to add a **Linked Server** on the Local machine to point to the server that hosts your remote data source.

Then modify your Dataset query in the SSRS report to look something like this...

```
select * from openquery(REMOTE_SERVER,'Put your original query here');
```